# MYSQL: #1146 Table '...' doesn't exist

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, mysql-procedimiento, mysqlprocedure

### ¿Por qué me sale tabla 'prueba.ParesImpares' no existe al llamar al procedimiento, cuando si la he creado?

En tu base de datos de pruebas, crea dos tablas llamadas pares e impares. Ambas deben tener una única columna llamada numero de tipo entero. Después crea un procedimiento busca_par_impar que reciba un parámetro de entrada llamado final de tipo entero y que almacene en la tabla pares aquellos números pares que existan entre el número 1 el valor introducido como parámetro. A su vez, tiene que realizar la misma operación para almacenar los números impares en la tabla impares. Ten en cuenta que deberá borrar el contenido de las tablas antes de empezar a insertar valores. Utiliza la estructura LOOP para resolverlo.

```
create table Pares(
numeroPar int);

create table Impares(
numeroImpar int);
```

Procedure

```
delimiter //
drop procedure if exists ParesImpares;//
create procedure ParesImpares(in final int)
    begin
        declare cnt int;
        set cnt=1;
        delete from ParesImpares;
        bucle:loop
            if (cnt>final) then
            leave bucle;
                if (cnt%2=0) then
                    insert into Pares values(cnt);
                else
                    insert into Impares values(cnt);
                end if;
                set cnt=cnt+1;
            end if;
        end loop;
    end;
//

call ParesImpares(6);
```

Comment: `prueba.ParesImapres`. es un fallo al escribir la pregunta en SO, o tienes una tabla mal definida? Fíjate que pone `I m a p r e s`